# What does Dir [ ] do?

Tags: ruby

I need to change some functionality in a Ruby script that somebody else wrote. I have never used Ruby before, but am very familiar with Python, which makes some things easier, however, I am struggling with the below code.

I am familiar with join, and I figured out that *.mdb gets all files ending in .mdb, but can't figure out what the enclosing Dir[] does.

Upon removing of Dir[] the output changes from a list of files simply to the string 'c:/*.mdb'.

Would anybody be able to explain please?

`mdb_files = Dir[::File.join('C:/', '*.mdb')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dir[]` will return array of paths which is similar to `Dir.glob`

You can read more about it [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Dir.html#method-c-glob)